# Hibernate looks for the wrong primary key

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

My entity has two foreign keys, one of those is the primary key. I read in the [JPA Wiki](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence) that if the child's (Procurement) primary key is the same as the parent's (Article) one, you establish a @OneToOne relationship.

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
public class Procurement implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @OneToOne
    // the child's primary key is the same as the parent
    @JoinColumn(name = "articleId", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Article article;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "supplierId", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Supplier supplier;
```

Following the standard approach, the JpaRepository should look like this:

```
@Repository
public interface IProcurementRepository extends
        JpaRepository<Procurement, Article>
```

However, if I want to call the findOne-method (which looks for primary key) delivering an "Article" object, Hibernate throws an exception.

> org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for
>   class de.willms.spring.myerp.model.Procurement. Expected: class
>   de.willms.spring.myerp.model.Procurement, got class
>   de.willms.spring.myerp.model.Article

*The DB table structure:*

Table "article" (ID, shortText)

Table "supplier" (ID, name)

Table "procurement" (articleID, supplierID, price)

What do I have to change so that I can find a "Procurement" record by the corresponding "Article" object?

Comment: your question is bit confusing. you said that **Procurement** is child and **Article** is parent but Procurement is not extending from Article. And also it is a bit weird that you have both **Id** and **OneToOne** annotations on something at the same time. **Id** represents a data column(or columns if composite key used) while **OneToOne** is actually a relationship between two tables. Could you provide your DB tables structure to let people help you out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found a special function in Hibernate (amazing, but hard to understand in the documentation) leading to a solution.

As soon as the primary key consists of several columns or, like in my case, relates to other tables, a special ID class has to be written.

```
@Embeddable    
public class Procurement_ID implements Serializable {

    /**
     * This attribute establishes the 1:1 connection to a record in the
     * "article" table. The column "articleId" is a foreign key to the column
     * "id" in the {@link Article} entity. (Warning: This is Hibernate
     * specific!)
     */
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "articleId", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Article article;

    /**
     * This attribute establishes the 1:1 connection to a record in the table
     * "supplier". The column "supplierId" is a foreign key to the column "id"
     * in the {@link Supplier} entity. (Warning: This is Hibernate specific!)
     */
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "supplierId", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Supplier supplier;
```

(Due to a more "normalised" data model, I switched to the composite primary key.)

Because of the @Embeddable annotation, this ID can be injected into the entity class.

```
@Entity
public class Procurement implements Serializable {

    /**
     * The composite primary key of the underlying table is defined in the
     * {@link Procurement_ID} class.
     */
    @EmbeddedId
    private Procurement_ID procid;
```

With me using this approach, Hibernate inserts a new record with positive foreign key check:

> [DEBUG] **Generated identifier:** component[article,supplier]{article=de.willms.spring.myerp.model.Article#1, supplier=de.willms.spring.myerp.model.Supplier#1}, using strategy: org.hibernate.id.CompositeNestedGeneratedValueGenerator
>
> ... (Flusing) ...
>
> [DEBUG] Listing entities: ...
>   de.willms.spring.myerp.model.Procurement{price=2.5, deliveryTime=10,
>   **procid=component[article,supplier]{article=de.willms.spring.myerp.model.Article#1,
>   supplier=de.willms.spring.myerp.model.Supplier#1}**, priceUnit=$}

However, it is a pity that the JpaRepository cannot inject find()-method stubs concering only one part of the primary key. It is "unable to resolve the attribute against the path". You are welcome to comment!

Comment: I think there are two problems here. First Spring Data has a problem with shared primary keys: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-649 Secondly, I'm having some problems with plain Hibernate to handle this, while EclipseLink works fine. But I don't understand why your Procurement_ID class also contains supplier? Isn't your primary key made of just article?

Answer (score 1):

You still have to use an id of type int or long. The difference is that instead of joining with `@JoinColumn`, you have to use `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn`. You class should look like this.

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
public class Procurement implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "articleForeignGenerator")
    /* Hibernate-specific generator needed for shared primary key */
    @GenericGenerator(name = "articleForeignGenerator", strategy = "foreign", parameters = @Parameter(name = "property", value = "article"))
    @Column(name = "articleId")
    private int articleId;

    @OneToOne
    // the child's primary key is the same as the parent
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private Article article;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "supplierId", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Supplier supplier;
```

Note that I use a hibernate-specific generator for the ID. It may be different for your JPA provider.

Comment: Sorry, but your solution leads to another exception:
"org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property [de.willms.spring.myerp.model.Procurement.article]"...I hope to find some approaches in the Hibernate documentation.

Comment: @PWillms are you sure to have one article for each procurement?

Comment: Yes, as seen from a meta level, I want to store procurement data concerning an existing article. The specific record is supposed be connected to a supplier record.

Comment: The exception you're getting seems to mean that you're trying to load or save a Procurement with an Article set to null.